# How to use log --full-diff only for a subfolder?

Tags: git, git-log

I am using the follow command:

`git log --color -p --full-diff master..upstream/master -- folder/subfolder`

The output of this command starts correctly showing just the changes inside the subfolder. But after that it also shows changes outside of the subfolder. How do I solve that problem?

PS: Please, don't suggest using git diff, because this command doesn't have equivalent behavior to git log --full-diff.